# Prevent img from stretching display: table

Tags: html, css, image, css-tables

I have a container with a fixed height, inside is an `<article>` with `display: table;` property. I want this `<article>` to fill his parent, both in height and width (`height: 100%;width: 100%;`).

The tricky part is this *table* has 3 children : a header and a footer, both with variable heights, and a third, main element, that should fill the remaining space.

The problem is, in that main element, I have an `<img>` bigger in height than the main container, stretching the *table*, despite the `height: 100%;` (illustration here :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3Mg1.png]

Is there a way to limit the img's height so that it doesn't stretch the table ? I tried `height/max-height: 100%` with no luck.

As the code needs to be IE9 compatible, I can't use a flexbox layout, hence the `display: table-*` approach.

Here's the full code and a codepen, notice how the table is bigger than its parent container (`<section>` with red border), due to the img : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGJLLa

**HTML**

```
<section>
  <article class="table">
    <header class="row">
        <h2>My header</h2>
    </header>
    <div class="mainrow row">
      <div class="vmiddle">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/abstract/" alt="Myimg" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum [...]</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="row">
      My Footer
    </footer>
  </article>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
section {
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 15em;
}

  .table {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
    .row {
      display: table-row;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }

    header { background-color: lightgrey; }
      h2 {
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 0.5em 0;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }

    .mainrow { background-color: lightyellow; }
      .mainrow>div {
        float: left;
        height: 100%;
        width: 50%;
      }
      .vmiddle {
        font-size: 0;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .vmiddle:before {
        content: '';
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100%;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }
        img {
          max-height: 100%;
          max-width: 100%;
          vertical-align: middle;
        }

    footer { background-color: lightblue; }
```

Thanks

Comment: your question is not clear? please provide little bit more info..ty

Comment: Tried to reformulate, and added an illustration, hope it's clearer now. Thanks